# Adding simple css to iframe/html

Tags: css, iframe

I have got some HTML code from investing.com below:

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" height="380" width="230" src="https://ssltools.forexprostools.com/currency-converter/index.php?from=17&to=12&force_lang=1"></iframe><br /><table width="197"><tr><td><span style="font-size: 11px;color: #333333;text-decoration: none;">The Currency Converter is powered by <a href="https://www.investing.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="font-size: 11px;color: #06529D; font-weight: bold;" class="underline_link">Investing.com</a></span></td></tr></table>
```

The output is look like the picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m11t.png)

And I would like to add css to make the background like below:
Rounded rectangle, 30 opacity with light green, maybe 10 px for margins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spceu.jpg)

Can anybody help me. I am new for html and css. Thank you very much.

Lawrence

Comment: The simplest and most cross-browser compatible way is not to try to style the iframe, but to create a rounded light green block in your own document and put the iframe inside it.

Comment: Because the code is generated by investing.com. so I just want to add the "color shell" to surround it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add wrapping `div` and css class `.frame {}` with colored border

```css
.frame {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 30px solid ;
  border-color: rgba(200,255,200,0.6);
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame"><iframe frameborder="0" height="380" width="230" src="https://ssltools.forexprostools.com/currency-converter/index.php?from=17&to=12&force_lang=1"></iframe><br /><table width="197"><tr><td><span style="font-size: 11px;color: #333333;text-decoration: none;">The Currency Converter is powered by <a href="https://www.investing.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="font-size: 11px;color: #06529D; font-weight: bold;" class="underline_link">Investing.com</a></span></td></tr></table></div>
```

```
<style>
    .frame {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 30px solid ;
      border-color: rgba(200,255,200,0.6);
      border-radius: 30px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
    <div class="frame"><iframe frameborder="0" height="380" width="230" src="https://ssltools.forexprostools.com/currency-converter/index.php?from=17&to=12&force_lang=1"></iframe><br /><table width="197"><tr><td><span style="font-size: 11px;color: #333333;text-decoration: none;">The Currency Converter is powered by <a href="https://www.investing.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="font-size: 11px;color: #06529D; font-weight: bold;" class="underline_link">Investing.com</a></span></td></tr></table></div>
```

Comment: The reason may be in your own styles in your page. it would be great if you'd show the code in your question.

Comment: should css comes first or html comes first?

Comment: ususally css comes before html, beside it css from answer answer should come after css-rules of the page.

Comment: but why I fail to combine css+html code. my situation is the css shows as word above the calculator and html is ok to be a calculator

Comment: you need to wrap css code between tags `<style>` and `</style>`

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it? Sorry, I am new to html and css. Thank you

Comment: I've appended the answer. have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works for me eventually. I will try to read it carefully to how to combine css+html from this example. Really appreciate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put the iframe to a div. In this example `.iframe-container`. So the HTML will look like this:

```
<div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe frameborder="0" height="340" width="210" src="https://ssltools.forexprostools.com/currency-converter/index.php?from=17&to=12&force_lang=1"></iframe>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table width="197">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span style="font-size: 11px;color: #333333;text-decoration: none;">The Currency Converter is powered by <a href="https://www.investing.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="font-size: 11px;color: #06529D; font-weight: bold;" class="underline_link">Investing.com</a>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Please note that I changed the with and height of the iframe since the form it was containing, was not matched with the initial attributes. You can reset it if you'd like.
Then write some CSS as below:

```
.iframe-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
iframe {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

See the result at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arashtad/9vm20415/).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I know that is my problem that I tried many times to combine those HTML and css together, but doesn't work.

My purpose is only want to have "a batch of code" to paste into the website.

Thank you for your concern.